# Adding data points to my dataframe is too slow, is there a faster way with Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have the following problem. Let's say that I have a `dataframe` called `file_data`, which has 3 columns `TS_ns`, `VALUE_NUMBER` and `Alias`

```py
         VALUE_NUMBER    Alias     TS_ns
0        0.116000        Name_1    3
1        3.448000        Name_2    34
2        6.106000        Name_3    7
3        4.048000        Name_4    54
4        4.358000        Name_5    32
```

I would like to take its datapoints and add them to a new dataframe, called `dataframe_var`, which is empty and has only a column called `Channel`:

```py
         Channel
0        Name_1
1        Name_2
2        Name_3
3        Name_4
4        Name_5
```

In order to obtain this:

```py
         Channel    3       34       7        54       32
0        Name_1     116000  nan      nan      nan      nan
1        Name_2     nan     3.448000 nan      nan      nan
2        Name_3     nan     nan      6.106000 nan      nan
3        Name_4     nan     nan      nan      4.048000 nan
4        Name_5     nan     nan      nan      nan      4.358000
```

and possibly reorder the column names by increasing value.

The procedure I use is the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

time_series = pd.Series( file_data.TS_ns )
value_series = pd.Series( file_data.VALUE_NUMBER )
alias_series = pd.Series( file_data.Alias )

for time_point, value_point, alias_point in zip( time_series, value_series, alias_series ):
    dataframe_var.loc[ dataframe_var.loc[ dataframe_var[ "Channel" ] == alias_point ].index[0], time_point ] = value_point
```

The problem is that this line:

```py
dataframe_var.loc[ dataframe_var.loc[ dataframe_var[ "Channel" ] == alias_point ].index[0], time_point ] = value_point
```

is really really slow and if I deal with medium (not so big) dataframes I must wait hours until it complete.

Do you know if there is a most efficient and faster way to add data to my dataframe? Thanks.

Comment: is that dataset too large? cause pandas sucks for larger dataset.

Comment: @Ameya It's [374891 rows x 13 columns]

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do.  if dataframe_var is empty, then the Channel column will never equal alias point. It  would be good if you add a small example dataframe, and an example of the expected output. Generally updating/changing a dataframe in a for loop is inefficient and there are many other methods, but it's hard to know which one would be best for your case

Comment: @EmiOB I slightly edited the question. Unfortunately cannot add an example dataframe, since it is too much big.

Comment: ahh that means around 5 mil data points eh? I would say try modin it really helps. It's just like pandas but way faster [check out here.](https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/quickstart.html)

Comment: @Ameya thanks a lot, but unfortunately I am constrained on Pandas since I am working on a machine in which I cannot install anything else

Comment: you can make a smaller example, of just a couple of lines not the whole data, and then an example of what the output should look like. If I run your code on some made up data it returns errors, because dataframe_var is empty, so channel will never equal alias_point. I'm just trying to understand what you're actually trying to achieve

Comment: @Ameya I regularly use panadas on dataframes with 10s of millions of rows with no issues, with a range of functions which are really quick it is more than enough for most people's data needs

Comment: @EmiOB it really depends on your machine also eh?

Comment: @Ameya to an extent, but I've used it on some old/not flashy machines and it's fine. Pandas is not optimised for looping through (like in this quesiton), but there are functions that can be used so you would never need to. So it really depends on your code also eh?

Comment: @EmiOB agreed eh! I'm not a professional, still figuring things out.

Comment: @Ameya I added examples dataframes to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
file_data.pivot(index='Alias', columns='TS_ns', values='VALUE_NUMBER')

TS_ns      3      7      32     34     54
Alias                                    
Name_1  0.116    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
Name_2    NaN    NaN    NaN  3.448    NaN
Name_3    NaN  6.106    NaN    NaN    NaN
Name_4    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  4.048
Name_5    NaN    NaN  4.358    NaN    NaN
```

No need to use a for loop (this is generally very inefficient with pandas dataframes, there is almost always a function which is much faster).  If dataframe_var is perhaps used to filter file_data in this process, you can merge the above output onto that to keep only desired Aliases:

```
 dataframe_var.merge(file_data.pivot(index='Alias', columns='TS_ns', 
 values='VALUE_NUMBER'), on='Alias', how='left')
```